# BSD/macOS updatedb spec?

Tags: osx, bsd, locate

For linux, the format of `mlocate`'s DB is documented [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/mlocate.db). Without diving into the source, is there a similar spec for BSD / macOS [`locate.database`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?locate(1)) available?